# Converting a Base Ten Number to Any Number

Tags: java

There are several similar threads around here that pose a question like mine but I am unable to find a solution that works relatively simply. Was wondering if you guys had any ideas.

---

I have some code that will take any base ten number and convert it to that number in base 1 to 11. It's when I start getting into things like hexadecimal format that I struggle because I need letters in addition to numbers for that base. I'm sure the solution is pretty simple but it is currently escaping me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TenToAny
{
    private int base10;
    private int newBase;


    public TenToAny(int ten, int base)
    {
        base10 = ten;
        newBase = base;
    }

    public void setNums(int ten, int base)
    {    
         base10 = ten;
         newBase = base;
    }

    public String getNewNum()
    {
        String newNum="";
        int original = base10;

        while(original > 0)
        {
            newNum = original%newBase + newNum;
            original = original/newBase;
        }
        return newNum;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
       String complete = base10 + " base 10 is " + getNewNum() + " in base " + newBase;

       return complete;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.toString(int,int)` has a radix parameter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)

Comment: Converting to a radix system of your choice is one step. Deciding on the alphabet to represent the digits of that radix system is another step.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I'm assuming that's off limits. This _seems_ like a school assignment.

Comment: ... Base 1... Whaaat?

Comment: @user3189142 - Base 1 is perfectly legit.  Or have you never counted on your fingers?

Comment: @user3189142 - Actually, an abacus is base 1 (though groups of base 1 elements are assigned to decimal digits).  Why do computers not use base 27?

Comment: @HotLicks I never said base 1 wasn't legit, but who wants to read `1111111111` for 10?

Comment: Who wants to read values in base 3 or base 5?  The program simply does something that is possible, regardless of the real utility.

Comment: @HotLicks "Base 1" really isn't legit.  A number expressed in base N has digits (or other characters) that represent values from 0 to N-1.  That means that in Base 1, only the digit 0 is possible, and you can't represent too many numbers with just a 0 digit.  (You can redefine things to make it work, and I've actually played around a bit with negative integer and non-integral bases.  But it's basically an entirely different concept.)

Comment: @ajb - Yes and no.  A "base" assigns a weight to each digit position in the number, and the value of the number is the sum of the weights of the digit positions multiplied times the values of the digits in those positions.  For base 2, the positions have, right to left, the weights 1, 2, 4, 8 ...  For base 1 the positions have the weights 1, 1, 1, 1 ...  It is true that in order to display a base 1 number you'll probably need to tweak your algorithm, but most of the concepts are unchanged.

Comment: @HotLicks Not sure most concepts are unchanged... There's a standard way for adding two numbers represented in a base--add each digit from right to left, and if the result is >= the base, subtract the base and carry.  I don't think this works in a "base-1" system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions.  I'm including this for instructional value, not because I think it's better than the other answer.  Replace:

```
newNum = original%newBase + newNum;
```

with

```
int digitValue = original % newBase;
char digit = (digitValue < 10) ? ('0' + digitValue) : ('A' + (digitValue - 10));
newNum = digit + newNum;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a String array, initialized with all the numbers / letters necessary, and instead of putting in the number to the end of the string, put the string at that index of the array instead, like so:

```
String[] myStringArray = { "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
```

Or, as @Alnitak mentioned, just use a String, and use the `charAt()` function:

```
String myString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

That way, if the remainder is 5, you get "5", if it is 13, you get "C", etc.

Comment: or just a single string `"0123456789ABC..."` and `.charAt(n)`